# Slicing list with respect to limits

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following problem regarding slicing arrays.

I have an array of the form:

`a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

and I would like to extract an array like this:

`b = [8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3]`.

I tried using usual declaration like: `b = a[-3 : 3]` but it returns an empty array since it's going over the array limit.

I can't figure out how I can extract this array in correct permutation.

Comment: Is your indexing system a loop? I think you would have to write a function to do this.

Comment: Yes, I also realized that now. For now, I can work with the answer given by NMme though.

Comment: Sorry, I thought they were numpy arrays not lists.

Comment: Suggest changing title to 'slicing list' not 'slicing array'.

Answer (score 4):

You can just concatenate the list slices you are looking for:

```
 b = a[-3:] + a[:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you preserve all of the array elements. For this, there is a function called [`roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> np.roll(a, 3)
array([8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

You can also use a negative number to roll the other way:

```
>>> np.roll(a, -3)
array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  0,  1,  2])
```